# By Adding CSS overflow to particular section, add scrollbar to whole page and page layout disturbed

Tags: html, css

When I add `overflow:auto` and `white-space:nowrap` to new-parent div then it adds a scrollbar to the whole page due to which navigation header and footer becomes like this:

[image]

```
.new-parent{
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.new-col-child{
    height:100%;
    display:inline-table;
    margin-left:-3px;
    width: 300px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E4;
}

<div class="new-parent">
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
     <div class="new-col-child"> ..... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try `body{overflow-x:hidden;}`?

Comment: could you share your codepen/jsfiddle or website link?It will be easy for us to help you after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Try setting the `width` of `new-parent` div to `100%`

```
.new-parent{
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `body{overflow-x:hidden;}` in combination with the above one ?

Comment: body{overflow-x:hidden;} solved the problem of navbar header, footer and page scroller added to page but new issue comes. please check the issue at this [Issue link](https://imgur.com/ieB0VJy)

Comment: Try to give max-width to the parent div of these drop down filters, so that the content stays in viewport and does not go beyond it.

Comment: I am afraid I won't be of much help until I check it, so will you able to share some more code or link reproducing the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

body{overflow-x:hidden;} should help

Comment: could you share website link to debug the code and see what is issue?

Comment: do you need to keep "all leads, all users, actual value and options " when you open left side menu?